# Unhandled Exception in Visual Studio 2017 : unsigned long at memory location 0x0023F6A0

Tags: unhandled-exception, visual-c++-2017

I'm trying to determine whether the User account in which application running is belongs to Admin group or not in Visual studio 2017 using VC++. But when I'm running the Program in IDE it stops at the end of given function with exception dialog which says "Unhandled exception at 0x7697B022 in Target.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x00CFF638. occurred". But I click on 'Continue' in IDE, the execution goes ahead and completes the Program execution.

```
BOOL TargetAppClass::IsUserInAdminGroup()
{
    BOOL fInAdminGroup = FALSE;
    DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    HANDLE hTokenToCheck = NULL;
    DWORD cbSize = 0;
    OSVERSIONINFO osver = { sizeof(osver) };

    // Open the primary access token of the process for query and duplicate.
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE,
        &hToken))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }


    OSVERSIONINFOEX ptrVerInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&ptrVerInfo, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    ptrVerInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
    ptrVerInfo.dwMajorVersion = 10;
    ptrVerInfo.dwMinorVersion = 1;

    DWORDLONG dwlConditionMask = 0;
    int op = VER_GREATER_EQUAL;

    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_MAJORVERSION, op);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_MINORVERSION, op);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, op);
    VER_SET_CONDITION(dwlConditionMask, VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR, op);


    if (!VerifyVersionInfoA(&ptrVerInfo, VER_MAJORVERSION, dwlConditionMask))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    if (ptrVerInfo.dwMajorVersion >= 6)
    {
        TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE elevType;
        if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevationType, &elevType,
            sizeof(elevType), &cbSize))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        // If limited, get the linked elevated token for further check.
        if (TokenElevationTypeLimited == elevType)
        {
            if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, &hTokenToCheck,
                sizeof(hTokenToCheck), &cbSize))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }

    if (!hTokenToCheck)
    {
        if (!DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityIdentification, &hTokenToCheck))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }
    }

    // Create the SID corresponding to the Administrators group.
    BYTE adminSID[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
    cbSize = sizeof(adminSID);
    if (!CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, &adminSID,
        &cbSize))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    // To determine whether a SID is enabled in a token, that is, whether it 
    // has the SE_GROUP_ENABLED attribute, call CheckTokenMembership.
    if (!CheckTokenMembership(hTokenToCheck, &adminSID, &fInAdminGroup))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    // Centralized cleanup for all allocated resources.
    if (hToken)
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = NULL;
    }
    if (hTokenToCheck)
    {
        CloseHandle(hTokenToCheck);
        hTokenToCheck = NULL;
    }

    // Throw the error if something failed in the function.
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwError)
    {
        throw dwError;
    }

    return fInAdminGroup;
}
```

I wanted to know what mistake I'm doing, what should be done to eliminate this exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is an try-catch block Error. When I removed version checking logic from the code, it starts working. probably "OSVERSIONINFOEX ptrVerInfo" this variables initialization has get skipped some how and it causes the error.